# Changing list elements by checking elements of same list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops, lambda

I don't know what title to give to this question. Please change it if you come up with something nice and relative to the following description:

I have some mathematical operations in a list like:

```
A=11
B=1+2
C=A+E
D=B+A
E=C+B
```

But as you can see there is a circular reference problem at `C=A+E` and `E=C+B`. To report such problem my calculator app will replace circular references with `<CIR_REF>`. This will result into this:

```
A=11
B=1+2
C=A+<CIR_REF>
D=B+A
E=<CIR_REF>+B
```

I am unable to form a logic for this. The closest logic I was able to reach is following but it does not even seem very optimized solution and I don't think it will give the desired result:

```
class Expression {
    public char ID; //Like A,B,C,D (operand representing this expression)
    public string value; //Contains the actual expression
}
List<Expression> expressions; //assigned outside the class containing this whole code.
public void ResolveCircularReference() {
    for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Count; i++) {
        List<string> Ops = Utility.GetOperands(expressions[i].value);
        if (Ops.Count > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < expressions.Count; j++) {
                if (Ops.Contains(expressions[j].ID.ToString())) {
                    expressions[j].value = expressions[j].value.Replace(expressions[j].ID, "<CIR_REF>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So is there any other optimized way to this using LINQ or LAMBDA expressions or even standard loops?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to finding circles in a directed graph. First look into google: https://www.google.com/search?q=finding%20circles%20in%20a%20directed%20graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way:

Extend your `Expression` class, Add two another `IsCyclic` & `ConnectedBy` properties

```
public class Expression
{
    public char Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsCyclic { get; set; }
    public char ConnectedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Method to get operands:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetOperands(string value)
{
    return Regex.Split(value, "[-+*/]");
}
```

Get Input values:

```
var expressions = new List<Expression>
{
    new Expression{Id = 'A', Value = "11"},
    new Expression{Id = 'B', Value = "1+2"},
    new Expression{Id = 'C', Value = "A+E"},
    new Expression{Id = 'D', Value = "B+A"},
    new Expression{Id = 'E', Value = "C+B"}
};
```

Now, detect expressions if they are cyclic and by which Id they connected are:

```
foreach (var expression in expressions)
{
    var operands = GetOperands(expression.Value);
    var localCopy = expression;
    foreach (var operand in
        from operand in operands
        from expression1 in expressions
        where operand == expression1.Id.ToString()
        && expression1.Value.Contains(localCopy.Id)
        select operand)
        {
            expression.IsCyclic = true;
            expression.ConnectedBy = operand[0];
        }
}
```

Now, Replace specific values with `ConnectedBy` with `"<CIR_REF>"`

```
foreach (var expression in expressions.Where(expression => expression.IsCyclic))
{
    expression.Value = expression.Value.Replace(expression.ConnectedBy.ToString(), "<CIR_REF>");
}
```

That's it.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my life. :)